# which is better to display list of objects using ListView in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a List of Objects(POIs- Point of Interested), and now I want to display them in a `ListView.

And the layout of the each item is a little complex.

For an POI object, I will display its `name` `address` `distance` and `picutre`(if any) and etc.

After google and search at Stackoverflow, it seems that I can use the `ArrayAdapter`.

As shown in this examle, I have to create a `Adapter` which extends `ArrayAdapter`, [for example](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) :

```
private class POIAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<POI> {

    private ArrayList<POI> items;

    public POIAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<POI> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            POI o = items.get(position);
            if (o != null) {
                    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                    TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
                    if (tt != null) {
                          tt.setText("Name: "+o.getName());                            }
                    if(bt != null){
                          bt.setText("Address: "+ o.getAddress());
                    }
            }
            return v;
    }
```

}

As you can see, I have to refer to the `view` elements in this adapter, so I think it is not the best choice because the layout of the POI item may change someday, then I have to change this adapter accordingly.

Then I found the `SimpleCursorAdapter` which can map columns from a cursor to views in an XML file, but it seems that I have to create my own `Cursor`.

So I wonder if which is better for implemention and possible extension?

Comment: If you already have an `ArrayList`, then I recommend you to stick with `ArrayAdapter`. As for updating the adapter to adapt to layout change, there is no way other than to change (update) the code itself.

Comment: @antimo: Since I have though that I can only update the `fromColumns` and `toView` if I use the `SimpleCursorAdapter`, do I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

1. You may want to choose `ArrayAdapter` if:

   - If you're using an array to hold the data.
   - The layout has some logic in it apart from simple mapping of data to UI elements (e.g. some elements are hidden, etc.)
2. `SimpleCursorAdapter` may be better if:

   - You already have a cursor with your data and your layout needs are simple.

It's hard to give a very general guidance as lots depends on exact requirements. Also, think about what you may want to do in the future. `ArrayAdapter` makes it easier to create complex layouts even if you need to make code changes to achieve that.